# When to define a GTK class, when to use signals?

Tags: c, oop, gtk

I'm fairly new to GTK, and am messing around with my first "serious" GTK (gtk+-3) app. I'd like to draw on the wisdom of others' experience about when it's suitable to define a new GTK class, or just use a "vanilla" GTK classes, and implement behaviour via signal handlers.

I've come across two examples so far:

### Custom Widgets

I'm creating a new widget: basically a GtkDrawingArea, which I use to display some data. I had originally assumed that the best way to implement this would be to subclass GtkDrawingArea, using `G_DEFINE_TYPE`, and provide my own draw callback:

```
static void mywidget_class_init(MyWidgetClass *klass)
{
    GTK_WIDGET_CLASS(klass)->draw = mywidget_draw;
}
```

However, it looks like I could implement exactly the same functionality without defining a new type, by just creating a vanilla GtkDrawingArea, and hooking up the appropriate signals during initialisation.

[My custom widget will eventually provide more than just the draw callback, as it needs to be interactive, but that comes later...]

### Application Windows

My application consists of a few different windows, which currently are vanilla GtkWindows:

```
struct myapp_somewindow {
    struct myapp *app;
    GtkWindow    *window;
    GtkWidget    *some_label_that_is_updated;
    /*... other window-specific fields */
}
```

When the myapp_somewindow struct is initialised, I create the GtkWindow with `gtk_window_new()`, and initialise the widgets/layouts/etc, and connect the signals. [I'll probably be using .ui files for the more complex cases eventually, but the windows are simple enough for now.]

This could be done my defining a new subclass of GtkWindow, but I'm not certain when the code overhead of defining the new class becomes worthwhile.

---

I'm aware that there's probably no strict rules for which approach to take, but are there any general guidelines to use when making these design decisions? Are there any major pitfalls of either approach?

Comment: http://www.gtkforums.com/ might be a better place to ask. My feeling is that you should bother defining your classes if you imagine that they might be subclassed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've worked on a fair few projects using GTK+ and Clutter and i've always promoted heavy use of subclassing of generic widgets / actors to more specific ones.

By convention with GObject you create a new file for each class and thus if you pull in the behaviour and state mechanics associated with your widget into a subclass you will pull that code into a separate file. This helps make it easier to structure your code and helps when someone else wants to come along and read it.

The subclassing strategy also helps you enforce encapsulation as a good practice on your code base. If your widgets and their associated state and logic are well encapsulated then that can help with reuse.

A good example of a project where this subclassing strategy has been used is tasks, and in particular it's internal helper library: http://git.gnome.org/browse/tasks/tree/libkoto This meant that when we wanted to port the application to a new platform or provide a different view on the data it was quite easy to just glue the existing widgets and tree models together in a different way.

If you want to use C and you find subclassing a bit tedious then you can try this tool: http://git.gnome.org/browse/turbine/ to help automate the creation of your subclasses.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use subclasses for everything? Otherwise, do you have any guidelines about when you wouldn't?

Comment: @Jeremy Not quite. I was suggesting to use subclassing where you're going to get a _potentially_ reusable component. It may not make sense to subclass the main `GtkWindow` for instance nor the intermediate boxes and so forth in the widget hierarchy between the top level and the widgets that do the real work. It's also about aesthetics - would this be clearer if this code were moved to it's own object and C file.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the guideline of defining a new class when you need to save some state for the widget. Otherwise, you'll end up creating custom structures holding that state to pass as user data to the signal handlers, making your code more complicated and creating more opportunities for memory leaks.

That would suggest that for your second use case, application windows, you should always define a new class.

One reason to do it this way is that your widget might start out simple, with behavior that you can implement purely with signal handlers, but later might become more complicated. For example, suppose you want to add a backing store to your drawing area. The "perceived cost" of refactoring your simple widget into a class is high, whereas it'll make your code much cleaner than working around it.

Another advantage is that classes can have properties. You can bind these properties to other classes' properties or to GSettings keys, which is a really powerful mechanism and can make your code really simple.

If you don't like all the class boilerplate, consider programming in Vala.

Comment: As shown in the second example (which doesn't use subclasses), I'm already creating a struct to contain state for the application window - it would have the same scope and lifetime as whatever GtkWindow struct I'd define as the subclass. The difference in this case is that the struct contains a `GtkWindow *`, rather than embedding a `GtkWindow`. In the backing store case, both methods would involve adding the backing store data to that struct.

Comment: Although, I guess the subclass approach frees-up the gpointer argument for signal handlers, allowing me to specify an additional pointer to the handlers, as I can (I think) reference the widget through other means. However, not sure when I'd require that extra pointer.